# How to show font awesome icon on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I have a link that is editable, if someone hover on that link there should be a fa fa-edit icon on hover

Here is the html code

```
<a href="#" class="btn" id="company_name" data-type="text" data-pk="3" data-name="company_name" data-title="Enter Company Name">Learn web programming</a>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
```

I want to show fa fa-pencil icon on hover only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple css can do the trick using [adjacent sibling selector(+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover). Also I've added slight variation in html that `&nbsp;` is wrapped by `span` for making symbol visible when it's hovers the icon.

```css
a:hover +span+ i, /* when link is hovered select i */
a + span:hover+ i, /* when space after link is hovered select i */
a + span + i:hover { /* when icon is hovered select i */
  visibility: visible;
}

a +span+ i { /* in all other case hide it */
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#" class="btn" id="company_name" data-type="text" data-pk="3" data-name="company_name" data-title="Enter Company Name">Learn web programming</a><span>&nbsp;</span><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the unicode in the font-awesome for fa-pencil (towards the bottom of the banner) and then use content:'f040' (f040 is the unicode for fa-pencil) and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Fontawesome icon with generated content on hover.. as @Rinku suggested

```
#company_name {
        position: relative;
    }

        #company_name:hover:after {
            content: '\f040';
            font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

and

`<a href="#" class="btn" id="company_name">Learn web programming</a>`